# How to get more questions, even if you know it all already

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, questions, beta

### As has been previously highlighted, this site needs more good questions.

This is a problem, as *good* questions do two things:

1. **They tell visitors that this is the site for them.** *Look! That's exactly the problem I had last week, and it took me three hours scouring message boards to solve it!*
2. **They give experts like you a way to share your expertise** in between your **really** complex problems that only another real expert can solve.

So we need good questions, and right now, we may not be getting enough for a reason that's a fairly high-class problem:

**We've got a lot of experts who want to help but may not *need* any help right now.**   This is a good kind of problem.   Our sites thrive when they're full of experts, because the serious students will follow them here to learn.

**So here's how you experts can help get enough content here to help get to a successful public beta:**

1. **Post an actual problem that you encountered in the past that was challenging to solve.**    Leave it up for a day or two to see what answers it gets, and then if the one you found was better, answer your own question, but only after you give your expert colleagues a shot. *Note that I'm **not** suggesting you make up questions - the best questions are always those that someone has actually encountered, even if you're not encountering it right now.*
2. **Send your colleagues, students, etc.** here to learn.  Use the referral link to bring others into the beta who may be more likely to be on the "needing help" side of the see-saw, and encourage them to ask questions.

Then help them!  We've got the most valuable thing here already, we just need to ensure we take advantage of it to build the critical mass you'll need to start a strong community.

---

Comment: is there a magic number that we are trying to reach?

Comment: On the [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce), it suggests 15 questions per day on average.